# R-markdown cannot change working directory. Used to work properly

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have R-markdown codes that used to work properly on my laptop. I just ran my codes and got the following error. I tried to re-install the knitr and markdown package but the problem still resists. Here is the error:

> cannot change working directory
>   Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> setwd
>   Execution halted

And here are the few first lines of my codes:

````
---
output: 
  html_document:
  toc: true
  number_sections: true
geometry: margin= 0in
include:
 after_body: footer.html
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE, warning = FALSE, message=FALSE}
#Edit theses values to change it throughout the report
county<-"Butler"
pubDate<- "June 2018"
citeDate<-"2013"
```
```{r, echo=FALSE, warning = FALSE, message=FALSE}
````

Comment: That's not a complete document, but it works fine on my system.  Do you get the error when you try to knit just what you posted?

Comment: Yes, that is the error message I received after knitting to HTML.

Comment: Knitting the original document, or the fragment you posted?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is going on, but when I re-run the code I do not receive that error anymore. Instead, I get this error: Error: Must supply a symbol or a string as argument. I think something should be wrong on the following portion of my codes:

```
  education.year <- acs %>% 
  filter(Sex == "Total", `Age Group`=="All", `County Name` == county) %>% 
  select(`6th Grade or Less`, `7th- 12th (No Diploma)`, `High School Graduate`, 
         `Some College`, `Bachelor's Degree`, `Graduate Degree`)  %>% 
  gather(c(`6th Grade or Less`, `7th- 12th (No Diploma)`, `High School Graduate`, 
           `Some College`, `Bachelor's Degree`, `Graduate Degree`), EduPerc)
```

P.S: My Rmarkdown code used to be work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I've had a problem like this it's been the knit directory setting that has tripped me up. Whilst it is not best practice to `setwd()` in a script, keeping a consistent practice of the knit directory settings (and noting this setting in the readme for others) will aid reproducibility.

For git version controlled code repositories, I favour the "Project Directory" knit setting, as this makes it consistent for Rmarkdown and R scripts and better allows for a subfolder layout such as that used for R package development (see [here](https://r-pkgs.org/structure.html))

[image]